# Cron task gets removed from the schedule

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, cron

I have a plugin which I have deployed on four different websites. 
Part of that extension is a Cron job which triggers every hour.

On one of my deployments my job gets removed from the schedule. I used WP Control plugin to add it again (avoiding the reinstall of plugin). It worked for some time but then it was removed again.

I checked the logs and the removal of job from the schedule coincides with these other Cron jobs that were running at about that time
**wp_update_themes**, **wp_update_plugins**, **wp_version_check**, **woocommerce_cleanup_sessions**

- Bellow is the list of the installed plugins:
- Advanced Custom Fields PRO
- Advanced Order Export For WooCommerce
- All In One SEO Pack
- Autoptimize
- Async JavaScript
- Complete Open Graph
- Custom Post Type UI
- Easy WP SMTP
- Disable Comments
- Gettext override translations
- Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)
- Invisible reCaptcha
- iThemes Security
- WooCommerce
- WP Super Cache
- WP Crontrol

Is it possible that some these plugins is removing my Cron job from the scedule?
What is causing this?

EDIT

This is how I add the Cron job in my init file of the plugin.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'hourly_processing');

function hourly_processing() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('process-subscriptions-hourly')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'process-subscriptions-hourly');
  }
}


add_action('process-subscriptions-hourly', 'process_subscriptions_hourly');


    function process_subscriptions_hourly() {

//I do the processing here.
}
```

Comment: There's no code to debug in your question, can you edit your question using the edit link under the tags to include the code that registers your cron job? It is possible but extremely unlikely that another plugin is removing your corn job, so unlikely I would not consider it worth investigating ( but if it was, you would need to ask their support routes as 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here ). Instead it's more likely that your use of WP Cron is not quite right, but I can neither confirm or rule this out because there is no code in your Q :(

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for your answer. I edited the question to show you how I include my hourly processing function in my plugin. What made me think it the interference of the other plugins is that I have the same system running on 3 other webistes where this doesn't happen. So that makes me suspicious of the plugins. One other thing that makes sense is server configuration. Would it matter if for example whatever I was doing in my process_subscriptions_hourly() function timed out for some reason?